# C# , compile in Linux system with Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

i have a C# project, and i want to compile it to a Linux machine. I have install Mono. At my attempt to compile it, i have an error:

The type or namespace name 'ListCollectionView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;


namespace SNAPoolLib
{
    public class ObservableList<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
    {

        ListCollectionView _p_view;
        public ListCollectionView _View
        {
            get
            {
                if (_p_view == null)
                {
                    _p_view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this) as ListCollectionView;
                }

                return _p_view;
            }
        }

        public ObservableList() : base() { }
        public ObservableList(IEnumerable<T> items) : base(items) { }
    }
}
```

Any answer to this would be helpful!

Comment: I guess `ListCollectionView` is platform-specific, and simply not exists in Mono (for Linux)

Comment: So, is there any way to import ListCollectionView to Mono ?

Comment: WPF (looks like you are trying to compile some WPF stuff) is NOT cross platform, as far as I know, so no, there is no way to import ListCollectionView on linux

Comment: I Found that ListCollectionView exists in Olive Project ( https://github.com/mono/olive) .Can this help my case?

Comment: not sure. This is looks like a _beta_ features of mono, and I know almost nothing about mono, except it is a CLR port for linux:\ I also know, if you google for "WPF for linux" you will find a bunch of some-sort-of-solutions.

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/ You need to completely forget about WPF on Linux (unless someone finishes the port). I do have a post on some options, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea